# Vertical Character Recognition

Tags: mobile, google-cloud-platform, ocr, vision, firebase-mlkit

I have tried couple of services like google vision,ML Kit & Azure but none were able to give me correct text detection output for vertically placed characters ex.
V
E
R
T
I
C
A
L

do you have any OCR that can help me solve this case ?.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I find that Google Lens is able to recognize such text correctly but I cannot find how to achieve this with ML Kit